# How to setup cgit with apache2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: server, apache2, git

I have tried to configure cgit with apache2 for many times but all failed.
Here are my configurations:

apache2 conf:

```
<VirtualHost *80:>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/cgit

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/home/git/repositories">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI
            DirectoryIndex /cgi-bin/cgit.cgi
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/htdocs/cgit">
         AllowOverride None
         Options +ExecCGI
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

cgit /etc/cgitrc:

```
# cgit configuration
virtual-root=/git/
enable-index-links=1
enable-log-filecount=1
enable-log-linecount=1
snapshot=tar.gz zip

logo=/cgit/cgit.png
css=/cgit/cgit.css

# repositories
repo.url=blc
repo.path=/home/git/repositories/testing.git
```

And the installation of cgit using the default configuration, ie. the docroot is in `/var/www/htdocs/cgit`, the executable cgi is under `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/`.

But when I tried to access `http://localhost/git` I always got this: `The requested URL /git was not found on this server.`

So where was I wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also the css and favicon files have moved to `/usr/share/cgit/` as displayed by `dpkg-query -L cgit`

Answer (score 3):

Have you enabled cgi in apache2 ? In xenial, it is not enabled by default.

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/cgi.load cgi.load
```

Worked for me with the Ubuntu package of cgit

Comment: The faster way of doing that would be to run `sudo a2enmod cgi`. The result is the same.